# Where can I get a GADBannerView ad from Xcode's object library

Tags: ios, admob, iad

iAd/AdMob mediation is not working. Only iAd banners always fill, AdMob never fills. I implemented mediation from AdMob, how can I get a GADBannerView to appear in Xcode's Object library so I can delete the AdBanner programatic version. Can it even be done on Xcode?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can find the answer from here.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?hl=en

Simply, There is no 'GADBannerView' object which you can drag into your view controller but you can change 'UIView' object to 'GADBannerView'.

In the Identity inspector in the top right corner, give this view the custom class GADBannerView..

I hope it helps you.